# Applying stain/polyurethane over mineral oil and wax

Tags: woodworking, refinishing

Can I stain and polyurethane an outdoor wood table top that has been treated with Butcher Block Conditioner containing mineral oil and natural waxes? The table is currently very weathered. We are trying to decide whether to reapply the Butcher Block oil and refinish at a later date or to simply sand, stain, and polyurethane the top now while it is weather worn. This table will remain exposed to the Florida elements.

Comment: How long did it last?  If less than a few years would suggest changing now.  Being exposed is hard on most finishes.

Comment: Could you post a picture so we can see how bad it is?

Comment: Polyurethane won't bond well with either of those finishes. You can try to use denatured alcohol to cut them, then let dry, sand. and apply a layer of shellac (as a primer). Sand dried shellac and apply high quality water-based poly (like General Finishes) to seal. As with everything, test on inconspicuous area.

Comment: For future reference, you may consider [woodworking.se] for questions like this. While this isn't "fine furniture", there is great expertise there on finishing and refinishing projects.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot apply it over mineral oil and/or wax but mineral oil eventually works it's way out of wood almost entirely which is why it needs to be continuously applied.  If it's been years since the last application I wouldn't be too concerned about the mineral oil but I would sand the whole thing down regardless to aid the poly adhesion and then clean it thoroughly with mineral spirits to remove any wax/oil that may be leftover.  The mineral spirits will also make any spots that are still coated with oil or wax very obvious as they will be discolored and indicate you should sand that area more.